# Conditional spatial join based on largest overlapped area

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, spatial-join

I have two layers (Buildings and Census areas) which are overlapped. I want to join them with a spatial join but, in some cases, buildings overlap two or more census units and I don't know which census unit associating to. So I thought that I could associate the building to the census area that is overlapped for the largest part. For doing this, I first want to evaluate if the intersected area is higher than the half of the building area. I tried in two ways (see code below) but they return different results.

**does someone know why the two codes return different results?**

> **1st trial**

```
featuresC= Census_layer.getFeatures()
featuresB=Building_layer.getFeatures()
count=0
for fbuild in featuresB: 
    BuildingGeometry=fbuild.geometry()
    if intersection.area()>0.5*BuildingGeometry.area():
        print intersection.area(), "featInters"
    else:
        print BuildingGeometry.area(), "featBuild"
```

> **2nd trial**

```
featuresC= Census_layer.getFeatures()
featuresB=Building_layer.getFeatures()
count=0
for fbuild in featuresB: 
    BuildingGeometry=fbuild.geometry()
    if intersection.area()*2.0>BuildingGeometry.area():
        print intersection.area(), "featInters"
    else:
        print BuildingGeometry.area(), "featBuild"
```

and, for instance, the results are:

```
         **1st trial             2nd trial**

    717.0162316 featBuild   717.0162316 featBuild
    215.4575371 featBuild   215.4575371 featBuild
    78.8431039  featBuild   50.23154609 featInters
```